# How can a large passenger airline in midair hover motionless for 10 minutes above my house? This happened in 12/2020

Tags: aerodynamics

A few weeks ago, sometime in December 2020, I walked outside to get my mail around 1300 and saw a large passenger plane hovering roughly 5000ft above my house. I watched it for 5 minutes when a UPS truck came to deliver a package to a neighbor.  I told them to look up to see what I was seeing.  We watched in amazement. Five minutes later, I noticed the plane start to inch forward. I watched it for another 15 minutes and it couldn't have been more than 5-10 miles away from me.  All this happened on a clear blue sky day, with just a slight breeze at ground level. I called the airport to see what they had to say and only got a recording to leave a message, so I did.  I never heard back from the airport tower, but I could not get the incident out of my mind. This occurred over Pasco, WA USA, and I would swear on a Bible that three of us saw the same phenomena. I know how plans can fly, and there had to have been one heck of a wind event for this to happen. Hopefully, someone can give me a reasonable explanation for what I saw. Marja Henderson, retired RN (1/17/2021)

Comment: That isn't possible, so whatever you saw was obviously not a large passenger jet.

Comment: How did you arrive at your estimates of 5000' and 5 -10 miles? Only possibility I can think of is a scale model . . . . what about engine sound?

Answer (score 6):

According to FlightRadar24, [SkyWest Flight 3830 took off from the Pesco Tri-Cities Airport at about 13:06 local time, flew directly over the city, then climbed away to the southeast](https://www.flightradar24.com/2021-01-17/21:05/12x/46.19,-119.18/11) (note: FlightRadar24 uses UTC time, so 13:00 local would be 21:00 UTC). You would have seen it directly tail-on as it climbed to its cruising altitude.

It's well known among pilots that, if you're on a collision course with another aircraft, then the aircraft will appear stationary in your field of view. So, if you see an aircraft that *appears* to not be moving, you better pay **very** close attention to it until you determine if you need to take evasive action or not.

I think what you saw was SkyWest 3830, but directly tail-on, so you wouldn't have seen any movement across your field of view. The fact that it was so far away meant you couldn't tell that it actually *was* moving directly away from you.

Comment: That's not compatible with alleged observations: "*Five minutes later, I noticed the plane start to inch forward. I watched it for another 15 minutes and it couldn't have been more than 5-10 miles away from me*". At the slowest acceptable airspeed, the aircraft would have disappeared from view.

Comment: @mins Not true. Even at cruise speed, a passenger jet could have remained in view for half an hour or more, and SK@3830 wasn't flying anywhere near cruise speed at that time. Five minutes after takeoff, it was only at about 20,000 feet and still climbing. After that point, the rate of climb slows (as would be expected from the thinning atmosphere) but forward speed doesn't, which results in the start of the apparent forward motion (because the plane is no longer flying directly away from the observer).

Comment: "*I watched it for another 15 minutes and it couldn't have been more than 5-10 miles away from me*". At, say, a slow 200 kt GS, in 15 minutes the aircraft travels 90 km, and is out of the sight, first by the effect of nebulosity/diffraction, and second because its angular size, smaller than the one of ISS at 400 km, is now below human eye resolution.

Answer (score 1):

There is an air force base near Spokane which is home to large jet planes, at which pilots train to fly them. It is possible that the pilots of that plane were practicing *slow flight*, where they set up the plane to stay in the air at the minimum possible (safe) speed. A big jet like a B-52 can be slowed to around 140 knots and remain just barely airborne, and in a 100MPH headwind the plane will be moving across the ground at 40 knots. If viewed from a mile away, it will look as if the plane is hardly moving at all.

In addition, if the pilots were practicing *stalls*, where the plane is going so slow that it is teetering right on the verge of falling out of the sky, they can "hang" the plane in the air by piling on full power and tilting the nose up so the engine thrust is helping maintain the plane's altitude at that (dangerously!) slow speed.

I invite the B-52 experts here to weigh in with their experiences regarding this.